# Blank settings screen for iOS app

Tags: ios, settings

I am trying to create a settings bundle for a new app. When I use the default version, that is correctly displayed, yet when I just touch the file, by adding and deleting a space, for example, I get a totally empty screen as you may see in the attached screenshot. What is worst is that, even I restore the original settings, the screen remains as such until I delete them altogether and recreate them after running the app once without the settings.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a general bug hopefully only affecting the development device. Quitting the settings restores it. To clarify the issue happens act second time the app is launched, even without touching the screen.